# Why can't I install new version of Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

My OS is CentOS 7, and I want to install PyTorch so I did the following:

```
(pt_gpu) [martin@A08-R32-I196-3-FZ2LTP2 mlm]$ conda -V
conda 4.6.2

(pt_gpu) [martin@A08-R32-I196-3-FZ2LTP2 mlm]$ conda install -c anaconda pytorch-gpu
```

What's strange is that the installation message shows that it is installing  a very old version of PyTorch:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/martin/anaconda3/envs/pt_gpu

  added / updated specs:
    - pytorch-gpu


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ca-certificates-2018.12.5  |                0         123 KB  anaconda
    certifi-2018.11.29         |           py36_0         146 KB  anaconda
    pytorch-gpu-0.1.12         |           py36_0        16.8 MB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        17.0 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1a-h7b6447c_0 --> anaconda::openssl-1.1.1-h7b6447c_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates                                 pkgs/main --> anaconda
  certifi                                         pkgs/main --> anaconda
  mkl                    pkgs/main::mkl-2017.0.4-h4c4d0af_0 --> anaconda::mkl-2017.0.1-0
  pytorch-gpu                                     pkgs/free --> anaconda


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
certifi-2018.11.29   | 146 KB    | ########################################################################################################################## | 100% 
ca-certificates-2018 | 123 KB    | ########################################################################################################################## | 100% 
pytorch-gpu-0.1.12   | 16.8 MB   | ########################################################################################################################## | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

To verify what's installed, I did:

```
(pt_gpu) [martin@A08-R32-I196-3-FZ2LTP2 mlm]$ python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
0.1.12
```

Why is it that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their official website( https://pytorch.org ) ,  they install package named pytorch,  not pytorch-gpu.

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

Comment: But I want to install the 'GPU' version, right? Like the tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: That's not a general convention. For PyTorch the distinction is `pytorch` (GPU version) vs `pytorch-cpu`. I don't even know what pytorch-gpu is, likely some very old version.

Comment: pytorch  is the 'GPU' version.  pytorch-cpu is the  'CPU' version.

Comment: This is installing the pytorch 1.0.0 rather than the latest ver which is 1.5.0. Any ideas whats causing it ?

Comment: This usually works for me, but I'm having a problem where it will only install the cpu version, even though I'm asking it to install `pytorch` (not the cpu version).